# Error in `pivot_longer()`: ! Can't combine `Stock1_name` <character> and `Stock1_dollars` <integer>

Tags: r, tidyr

I currently have wide data that I'm trying to convert to long data. In wide, it's organized in these columns:
ID | PlanName | Year | State | Stock1_name | Stock1_dollars | Stock2_name | Stock2_dollars

This continues all the way to Stock10_dollars.

I'd like to tidy this so it's organized like this:
ID, PlanName, Year, State, Stock, Dollars

I run the code below and get the error:

> *Error in pivot_longer(): ! Can't combine Stock1_name and Stock1_dollars .*

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to R and just running into a wall trying to figure this out.

```
after_data <- before_data %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("Stock"),
    names_to = c(".value", "name"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) %>%
  select(-name)
```

Comment: Likely answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253987/parallel-pivot-longer-of-two-sets-of-columns

Comment: Here's an example: `data.frame(ID = "A", Plan = "Ab", Year = 2024, Stock1_name = "stock 1", Stock1_dollars = 100, Stock2_name = "stock 2",  Stock2_dollars = 200) |>  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Stock"), names_to = c("num", ".value"), names_sep = "_")`

Comment: `before_data %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Stock"), names_to = c(".value", NA), names_sep = "_", values_transform = as.character)` should do the trick